# Port does not close

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am using a serial port event handler very similar to the code below.  Nothing fancy and it works fine... most of the time.  I have been able to induce an error by unplugging the serial port connection, waiting for a bit, then plugging it back in.  After I close the application, I have discovered that it is not closing the port so I can't reopen the port.  It does not throw an exception when it locks up, it just stops reading.  I have to reboot the machine to force it to release the port.

I have some ideas but if anyone can offer some suggestions without shaming me, I would greatly appreciate it.  One caveat to this that may be causing a problem is that I am using a third party app to share serial ports.  My app must shadow a mission critical app that CANNOT be closed.

```cs
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;

class PortDataReceived
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM1");

        mySerialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
        mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
        mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;
        mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        mySerialPort.RtsEnable = true;

        mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);

        mySerialPort.Open();

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ReadKey();
        mySerialPort.Close();
    }

    private static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
        Console.WriteLine("Data Received:");
        Console.Write(indata);
    }
}
```

There are no exceptions thrown or error messages.

Comment: Have you tried registering and handling ErrorReceived and PinChanged Events?

Comment: _" I am using a third party app to share serial ports"_ Does this App handle that situation correctly? If you are dependent on it and it doesn't you need to look for a replacement.

Comment: " After I close the application," I would suggest to use a try-finally block, or implement IDisposable. In the end you can make sure to close the port (if it is still open) before the application closes.

Comment: Thank you.  I will add that code.  Ultimately I would like the user notified when the port connection is lost and force the user to close the port (fix the problem) then re-open the port.  I think if I just check to see if the original port is available then throw an error message if it is not.  Still playing around with the methods in serial ports to see what might work.